# Unwanted Transparent System Navigation Bar

Tags: android, flutter

I'm testing my Flutter application on a physical tablet (Nvidia Shield K1). I've created a custom input dialog since the application will be running in Landscape, and the user won't be able to see the TextField if the keyboard covers the screen.

One strange thing about this, is that when the keyboard is out, the System Navigation Bar is transparent, even though I never set it to be.
Even when I set it explicitly to be black, it is still transparent.

```dart
await SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
));
```

On Emulators, the System Navigation is black by default.
[image]

What can I do to fix this issue? It's clearly on this specific OEM, but it doesn't make sense why it would happen.